# Cardinal exponentiations inequality

Tags: set-theory, cardinal-arithmetic

Let $\kappa < \beth_2$ and $\lambda<\beth_1$ be cardinals. What can we say about $\kappa^{\lambda}$ without assuming CH? Is it true that $\kappa^{\lambda} < \beth_2$ or $\kappa^{<\beth_1} < \beth_2$?

Comment: The title was changed to something I disagree with, because "exponent" refers to a quantity denoted by a superscript, and we are not concerned with inequalities between these, but rather with values of exponentiation as a binary operation on cardinals. Thus, I think the original title was more correct than the so-called "improvement" by user64494 -- even if the plural of "exponentiation" sounds awkward to some ears.

Comment: @ToddTrimble I agree and have rolled back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if CH holds, this can break.

Suppose $\beth_1=\aleph_1$ and $\beth_2=\aleph_{\omega+1}$. Let $\lambda=\aleph_0$ and $\kappa=\aleph_\omega$. By [Konig's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)) we know that $\kappa^\lambda=\kappa^{cf(\kappa)}>\kappa$; since $\kappa^+=\beth_2$ this means $\kappa^\lambda\ge\beth_2$ (which in turn means $\kappa^\lambda=\beth_2$, of course).

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand.